# What is the standard/comprehensive reference for grammatical number in different languages?

Tags: translation, grammatical-number

I am a novice in this area so apologies if I use the wrong terminology.

For the purpose of content localization, I am seeking an easy and reliable reference for how numbers map to different plural forms in various languages.

For example, in English 1 (and -1) use singular and all other numbers use plural.

As I understand it, languages like Polish have different rules (ends in 1 but not in 11 uses singular, ends in 2/3/4 but not in 12/13/14 uses plural, all others use genitive plural).

How can one look this up for an arbitrary language?

Comment: 1 uses singular and all others plural? What does that mean? Ok, so, it depends on the use in context.

Comment: In Polish, ends in 2/3/4 but not in 12/13/14 uses _plural_, all others use _genitive plural_.

Comment: @downvoter why the downvote?

Answer (score 1):

I found https://www.unicode.org/cldr/charts/43/supplemental/language_plural_rules.html, which seems like a perfect resource.

Comment: Just remember that knowing which number and case of a noun to use with which numeral isn’t necessarily enough; in many cases, the noun itself also matter. For example, in Chinese, the noun and the context determines which measure word to use (e.g., when counting 人 [people] in a general context, you’d count 一/两/三**个**, but if it’s the number of people for a booking, it would be 一/两/三**位**); or in Irish, both the number (singular/plural) and the initial mutation depends on the noun (e.g., _cat_ vs _ceann_ vs _bróg_: 2 _chat/cheann/bhróig_, 3–6 _chat/cinn/bhróg_, 7–10 _gcat/gcinn/mbróg_.

Comment: Plus suppletion comes into it as well. Consider Russian 1 год, 2 года, 5 лет. The form годов does not occur with numerals as you would expect from many other nouns.

Comment: @OmarandLorraine Or even English: 1 person, 2 people.

Comment: Thanks for the additional detail!